# Linear Maps, Vector Spaces, Sequences

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T \in \text{ Lin}(V , V )$, then there exists a finite list of scalars $a_0, a_1,\cdots, a_r$, not all zero, such that 
$$a_0 x+a_1 T(x)+a_2 T^2(x)+\cdots + a_r T^r(x) = 0$$
for all $x\in V$. Hint: consider the sequence of powers $(I,T,T^2,T^3,\cdots)$ in the finite dimensional space $\text{Lin}(V,V)$.

Is this question meant to be solved with induction, and in that case imagine that $a_0(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then $a_0$ must be $0$, which is a contradiction?Where am I going wrong...

Comment: Try to follow the hint: First of all, what is the dimension of $Lin(V, V)$ (in terms of the dimension of $V$)?

Comment: It is the dimension of V=n squared.

Comment: Yes, so every set in $Lin(V, V)$ with $n^2 +1$ elements is linearly dependent.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean here I am very confused where are you getting n^2 + 1.

Comment: If a vector space is $m$ dimensional, then any $m+1$ sets of vectors are linearly dependent.